# How to find nodes using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, beautifulsoup, findall

I have a html code:

```
<table>
<tr>
   <td><table><tr><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>2</td></tr></table></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><table><tr><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>4</td></tr></table></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want to find all tr in first table.
I usually using

```
for tr in soup.findAll('tr'):
```

But i will get all tr (tr in main table and in sub table). How to get tr in main table only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("""
<table>
<tr>
   <td><table><tr><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>2</td></tr></table></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><table><tr><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>4</td></tr></table></td>
</tr>
</table>
""")

for tr in soup.find('table').find_all('tr', recursive=False):
    print tr
```

`recursive=False` helps to find only top-level tags (see [docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-recursive-argument)).